# owasp Dependency check suppression for a specific CVE entry through out the project

Tags: owasp

I am trying to suppress a CVE entry which is not relevant to our project. I have tried the below suppression method
I am trying to suppress false positives in the dll residing in any of the folder in "Mgmt"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suppressions xmlns="https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-suppression.1.2.xsd">
  <suppress>
    <notes><![cdata[
    this suppresses a specific cve for any *.dll in any directory.
    ]]></notes>
    <filepath regex="true">.*\Mgmt\.dll</filepath>
    <cve>cve-2014-9152</cve>
  </suppress>
</suppressions>
```

But I am unable to suppress it. However with using shal1, I can do the suppression. Since its more that 80 entries, doing the suppression with sha1 is not a good option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried providing all the cpe corresponding to the CVE entries. Thereby not providing individual sha1.

```
<suppress>
    <notes><![CDATA[
    file name: temp.dll
    ]]></notes>
    <cpe>cpe:/a:microsoft:services</cpe>
    <cpe>cpe:/a:services_project:services</cpe>
    <cpe>cpe:/a:app_project:app</cpe>
    <cpe>CVE-2014-9152</cpe>
</suppress>
```